# Universal calendar format

Tags: web, calendar

Is there a universal calendar format? I've been reading up on iCalendar, but that does not seem to be universal any longer.

Here is my problem:

I have constructed a web site for a client. They have a calendar at the site. I want to be able to export the data in that calendar to the calendar in your phone or computer. I tried iCalendar as mentioned above, but Windows does not recognize it, and nor does iOS. I've exported the data as a text file with the .ics ending and the MIME text/calendar.

Anybody out there with some pointers on where I can get information on how to export a generic format that works for all?

Comment: ISO-8601-formats are in widespread use for locale-independent exchange of dates and times. Many software components have at least partial support for this specification.

Comment: That is only a standard for date and time formats, not a standard for a format which can be imported into most common calendars (Windows, iOS and Android mainly).